# How can I sort odd and even row numbers in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I sort odd and even row numbers consecutively in SQL? For example, for a table of five lines:

| Row Number | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 3 | D |
| 5 | E |

Comment: What would you want to get as as a result out of what you posted?

Comment: I want to sort the row numbers as in the table I give above.

Comment: I want to sequence odd and even row numbers

Comment: @Littlefoot I think the table in the question **is** the result. The first two rows contain only even numbers in ascending order and the last three rows contain only odd numbers in ascending order. Hence I think that the OP is asking for a SQL query that will produce the table in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the order by clause:

```
select column1
  from table
 order by mod(column1, 2),
       column1;
```

MOD(n2, n1): MOD returns the remainder of n2 divided by n1 (in Oracle).

Comment: It didn't work like above table. How can I do as in the table above?

Comment: Can you show us the name of your table and the names of its columns?

Comment: My table like above.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select * from emp where (rowid,0) in (select rowid, mod(rownum,2) from emp);
```

ODD :
EVEN:

```sql
select * from emp where (rowid,1) in (select rowid, mod(rownum,2) from emp);
```

Comment: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This answer does not sort the results as requested; instead it merely limits the selection.(WHERE rather than ORDER BY).